# UWP VisualStateManager.GoToState Always Returns False

Tags: c#, validation, xaml, uwp, visualstatemanager

I am trying to use visual states to mark a TextBox input as invalid (by changing its border color to red) during input validation when a user submits a form the TextBox is a part of. I have the following code:

**XAML**

```
<Page.Resources>

    <!-- Other resources omitted for brevity -->

    <Flyout x:Key="NewTimeBlockFlyout">
        <StackPanel>

            <!-- Other stuff here omitted for brevity -->

            <TextBox Margin="5"
                     Header="Name"
                     x:Name="NewTimeBlockNameTextBox">
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Default"></VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Invalid">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Target="NewTimeBlockNameTextBox.Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                   </VisualStateGroup>
               </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            </TextBox>

        <!-- The rest of the form omitted for brevity -->

        <Button x:Name="CreateTimeBlockButton"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Margin="0,0,2,0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                Tapped="CreateTimeBlockButton_Tapped">Create</Button>
        </StackPanel>
    </Flyout>
</Page.Resources>
```

Note: This is on a XAML `Page`. I am NOT using a custom control.

**C#**

```
private void CreateTimeBlockButton_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // Validate the input.
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.NewTimeBlockNameTextBox.Text))
    {
        // These two lines of code confirm the visual state named "Invalid" does exist on the textbox.
        //List<VisualStateGroup> m = VisualStateManager.GetVisualStateGroups(this.NewTimeBlockNameTextBox).ToList();
        //List<VisualState> c = m.FirstOrDefault().States.ToList();

        // Assignment to bool just used to inspect the return value for debugging.
        bool did = VisualStateManager.GoToState(this.NewTimeBlockNameTextBox, "Invalid", false);
    }
}
```

**Problem**

No matter what I try, the call to `VisualStateManager.GoToState()` is always returning false.

**Things I have tried:**

Here is the [relevant documentation from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.visualstatemanager.gotostate?view=winrt-19041).

As seen in the C# code above, I have verified the visual state "Invalid" does exist, as expected, on the "NewTimeBlockNameTextBox" control.

I have seen several solutions including [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44804553/uwp-visualstatemanager-gotostate-does-not-work), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20483686/visualstatemanager-gotostate-returns-false-and-visual-state-is-not-changed) that suggest moving the `<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>` tag in the XAML to outside of the `TextBox`, or to the root of the `Page`. Neither have worked for me.

I have also seen these two solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61570833/visualstatemanager-gotostate-not-working-for-textbox-uwp) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13799103/visualstatemanager-gotostate-returns-false-in-onnavigatedto-method), but neither seemed relevant to my situation, as both seem to have issues related to things I am not doing.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce your issue. You need to place `<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>` outside the TextBox and skip status through `VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Invalid", false);`  Please refer to the following code.

Xaml code:

```
<Page
   ……
   Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <StackPanel>
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup>
                <VisualState x:Name="Default"></VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="Invalid">
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Target="NewTimeBlockNameTextBox.BorderBrush" Value="Red"></Setter>
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

        <TextBox  Margin="5"
                     Header="Name"
                     x:Name="NewTimeBlockNameTextBox" >
        </TextBox>       
     
            <Button x:Name="CreateTimeBlockButton"
                Grid.Row="1"
                Margin="0,0,2,0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                Tapped="CreateTimeBlockButton_Tapped">Create</Button>

        </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

Code behind:

```
   private void CreateTimeBlockButton_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {                         
        bool a = VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Invalid", false);         
    }
```

**Updated:**

For using VisualStateManager.GoToState(), which always be done by changing its controltemplate.

You could right click the textbox in XAML designer, then select the option **Edit a Template**->**Edit a Copy**, here you will see the default textbox style placed in `<Page.Resources> </Page.Resources>` tag.

```
<Style x:Key="TextBoxStyle1" TargetType="TextBox">
……
<Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="TextBox">
                    ……
                           <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
……
                             <VisualState x:Name="TestState">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BorderElement" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="red"/>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="HeaderContentPresenter" …/>
<Border x:Name="BorderElement" …/>
……
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
  </Style>
```

As you can see, you could place custom state in its template, then you could use “`VisualStateManager.GoToState(NewTimeBlockNameTextBox, "TestState", false);`” to skip state.

Comment: I tried this, and it does not work. `VisualStateManager.GoToState()` still returns `false`. Also worth noting, and I discovered when trying this, `<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>` tag MUST be before ALL child tags of the `<StackPanel>` tag, otherwise the XAML will not compile.

Comment: If you can’t do this, you could use another way instead, It is recommended to change its style. I have updated my answer, you could follow it.